# Trying to figure out where the variable "now" in this requestAnimationFrame function comes from, or how to obtain its value dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, requestanimationframe

Basically i been trying to create a game using multiple slot machine rollers. I have tried many versions to obtain my goals, and all work perfectly on pc, but as soon as i put them on a mobile device, they are laggy. this is mainly because i was manipulating dom elements, as i found out.

I found a function on the net, i have replicated it and run it in an app and it works perfectly.

Now im trying to write this function into my actual app, with my own variables.

My problem is this:

There is a variable called "NOW", that is passed to the function animate(); I am trying to figure out where it comes from and or how to dynamically create it myself. There is a requestAnimationFrame request in this function and after hours and hours of research, i still cant find anything.

here is a fiddle where the code is located:
https://codepen.io/indamix/pen/lLxcG

```
    var sm = (function(undefined){
    var tMax = 3000, 
    height = 210,
    speeds = [],
    r = [],
    reels = [
        ['coffee maker',   'teapot',       'espresso machine'],
        ['coffee filter',  'tea strainer', 'espresso tamper'],
        ['coffee grounds', 'loose tea',    'ground espresso beans']
    ],
    $reels, 
    $msg,
    start;

    function init(){
    $reels = $('.reel').each(function(i, el){
        el.innerHTML = '<div><p>' + reels[i].join('</p><p>') +   '</p></div><div><p>' + reels[i].join('</p><p>') + '</p></div>'
    });

    $msg = $('.msg');

    $('button').click(action);

    }

    function action(){
    if (start !== undefined) 
    return;

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        speeds[i] = Math.random() + .5; 
        r[i] = (Math.random() * 3 | 0) * height / 3;
    } 

    $msg.html('Spinning...');
    animate();
    } 

    function animate(now){  
    if (!start) start = now;

    var t = now - start || 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        $reels[i].scrollTop = (speeds[i] / tMax / 2 * (tMax - t) *             (tMax - t) + r[i]) % height | 0;
    if (t < tMax)
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    else {
        start = undefined;
        check();
    }
  }
    function check(){
    $msg.html(
    r[0] === r[1] && r[1] === r[2] ?
    'You won! Enjoy your ' + reels[1][ (r[0] / 70 + 1) % 3 | 0     ].split(' ')[0]  : 'Try again');}
  return {init: init}
   })();$(sm.init);
```

I've been at this for a while now, like days. I figured out that the Now variable has something to do with the requestAnimationFrame function to determine where the animation frame ends up,But this is only speculation for me.. I can't see it.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you're attempting to accomplish. Can you clarify? The callback function you pass into requestAnimationFrame accepts a parameter with the current elapsed ms since [time origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). You can't replace this with your own argument, and I don't follow what this has to do with DOM manipulation/performance, exactly. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `performance.now()` as an argument value to your own `animate` function call

Comment: Thanks for the reply Aleksey. Could you possibly give me a small example to show how to pass this performance.now() variable?

Comment: `animate(performance.now());` after `$msg.html('Spinning...');`

Comment: aaahhh gees thanks A stack Aleksey, its working like a charm.. Theres just one more thing, in the requestAnimationFrame(animate) do i have to pass the now variable? and is so, how would i do this? like so: requestAnimationFrame(animate.bind(now))..

Comment: No need, requestAnimationFrame does this job for you

Comment: great, thanks a stack Aleksey.. I been at this for days now.. Have a great one.. Regards Antony